# IE Network Setting not changing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

This is the screenshot which you can see where all option in internet settings panel are enabled but any modification is not appling:

[image]

Here is the issue how it is observed.

1. after windows started up, for a while, i can change those network settings.
2. Not sure when exactly, after some time those settings never saves if i disable/enable/modify. No other abnormal behavior observed which may cause this lockdown of the settings.
3. When this lock down happens, any change i do and hit OK button then open them back shows the old setting still there.
4. this happens every reboot.

   - OS : Windows 7
   - IE : 10
   - Antivirus : McAfee Enterprise

No virus/malwares were noticed running.

Tried to play with registry changes like below, but none working for me.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections]
- SavedLegacySettings
- DefaultConnectionSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i wasn't able to find a good solution for this current issue, but here is the workaround.

Make your network setting as global instead of per-user by modifying/or creating the registry key.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
ProxySettingsPerUser=dword:00000000
```

With this when any proxy/network config changes done in IE will result in the update of registry in the following location

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
```

instead of

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
```

This seems solved my current issue.